# how to select a unique record in a table which has no key constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I had a table named `uniq_select_records` with the following columns:

```
sno number, 
item_name varchar2(50),
start_date date, 
end_date date, 
action_flag char(1),
last_modified_date date, 
creation_date date
```

`sno` is a column which I used to identify a row for a `item_name` and it is not unique or primary key but it was not null. `sno` will be present for each item. no of items is equal to no of `sno`. sample

```
sno item_name start_date  end_date Action_flag last_modified creation_date
--- --------- ----------  -------- ----------- ------------- -------------
1   sample1   02-MAY-15  27-MAY-14    A        07-MAY-15        02-MAY-15
1   sample1   02-MAY-15  27-MAY-14    D        07-MAY-15        02-MAY-15
1   sample1   27-APR-15  06-JUN-14    C        07-MAY-15        02-MAY-15
1   sample1   27-APR-15  06-JUN-14    C        07-MAY-15        03-MAY-15
2   sample2   07-MAY-15  11-FEB-15    C        07-MAY-15        22-JAN-15
2   sample2   07-MAY-15  11-FEB-15    A        07-MAY-15        22-JAN-15
2   sample2   07-MAY-15  01-FEB-15    C        12-MAY-15        12-MAY-15
```

**Action flag values C=change, D='Deleted and A=insert**
sample data is shown above. like this we have millions of records. now we have to select the to record which had the latest change for each item. ***each item may have its own start_date and end_date***.**All the items weren't modified on the same date.**

Can anyone suggest idea how to fetch the records for each item which are latest change for an item.

thanks in advance.

Comment: as marked this question is not similar to the above link

Comment: dear friend the the following query

`select distinct  sno,item_name,max(start_date) over(partition by sno),max(end_date) over(partition by sno),max(creation_date)  over(partition by sno),
max(last_modified_date)  over(partition by sno) 
from uniq_select_records
order by sno,item_name asc;`

Comment: @Smart003 thanks its working, the query gives an accurate result which i was expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sno, item_name, max(last_modified)
  FROM uniq_select_records
GROUP BY sno, item_name
```

Comment: I dont think thats what he wants

Comment: assuming the sno and item_name do not change between the 2 days they were modified, you will get 2 records and not 3.